# How do I disable resolveJsonModule for a single JSON file in a NextJs application?

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, tsconfig, webpack-5

I'm building a nextjs application, deploying with vercel. Everything has been working fine, until I recently made some changes to a large json file which further increased its size by around 20%. The increase in size seems to have broken some kind of limit, and I'm now getting webpack 5 errors, which seem to be due to typescript type resolution.

I'm importing the JSON file directly with an import. From what I've been able to gather, it seems the resolveJsonModule compilerOption in tsconfig.json is responsible for telling webpack to attempt to resolve the types of the JSON files on the fly, so that presumably it can check I'm doing sensible things with the JSON file.

It's actually quite a simple file - it's just an array of fairly simple FoodItem objects as follows (illustrative example below):

```
import allFoodOriginal from '../data/all-food-data.json'

interface FoodData {
  Calories: string,
  Kilojoules: string
}

interface FoodItem {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  folders: string[],
  slug: string,
  image?: string,
  data?: FoodData
}

const allFood = allFoodOriginal as FoodItem[]
```

The JSON file itself is around 1.4 million lines long, which is around 82021 items. It seems this is just too big, as throws the error in the below logs when compiling in the vercel deployment.

```
14:39:23.522    Installing dependencies...
14:39:28.885    npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.14.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
14:39:28.896    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @next/swc-darwin-arm64@11.1.2 (node_modules/@next/swc-darwin-arm64):
14:39:28.896    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @next/swc-darwin-arm64@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
14:39:28.907    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc@11.1.2 (node_modules/@next/swc-win32-x64-msvc):
14:39:28.908    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
14:39:28.922    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
14:39:28.922    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
14:39:28.933    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @next/swc-darwin-x64@11.1.2 (node_modules/@next/swc-darwin-x64):
14:39:28.933    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @next/swc-darwin-x64@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
14:39:28.934    
14:39:28.935    updated 1 package in 4.846s
14:39:29.060    
14:39:29.060    50 packages are looking for funding
14:39:29.060    run `npm fund` for details
14:39:29.061    
14:39:29.847    Detected Next.js version: 11.1.2
14:39:29.850    Running "npm run build"
14:39:30.131    
14:39:30.131    > nextjs-with-typescript@4.0.0 build /vercel/path0
14:39:30.131    > next build
14:39:30.132    
14:39:30.868    info - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
14:39:31.072    info - Checking validity of types...
14:45:11.987    
14:45:11.989    > Build error occurred
14:45:12.003    RangeError: Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined
14:45:12.004    at Map.set (<anonymous>)
14:45:12.004    at recursiveTypeRelatedTo (/vercel/path0/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62613:30)
14:45:12.004    at isRelatedTo (/vercel/path0/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:62112:34)
14:45:12.004    at checkTypeRelatedTo (/vercel/path0/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:61742:26)
14:45:12.004    at isTypeRelatedTo (/vercel/path0/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:61694:24)
14:45:12.005    at removeSubtypes (/vercel/path0/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:58445:33)
14:45:12.005    at getUnionType (/vercel/path0/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:58547:31)
14:45:12.005    at checkArrayLiteral (/vercel/path0/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70038:17)
14:45:12.005    at checkExpressionWorker (/vercel/path0/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:76283:28)
14:45:12.005    at checkExpression (/vercel/path0/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:76204:38)
14:45:12.146    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
14:45:12.146    npm ERR! errno 1
14:45:12.150    npm ERR! nextjs-with-typescript@4.0.0 build: `next build`
14:45:12.150    npm ERR! Exit status 1
14:45:12.151    npm ERR!
14:45:12.151    npm ERR! Failed at the nextjs-with-typescript@4.0.0 build script.
14:45:12.151    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
14:45:12.157    
14:45:12.157    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
14:45:12.158    npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2021-10-26T13_45_12_151Z-debug.log
14:45:12.174    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Locally running `npm run build` I simply get a Javascript heap out of memory error.

I am happy to not bother with type checking the JSON file, but I don't know how to disable the type checking from within my NextJs application.

If I set resolveJsonModule to false, it is automatically set back to true by the build process which claims to know better.

Are there any options for disabling the type check for this JSON file only?

**Update**

It is apparently possible to overcome this specific type checking error by loading the JSON file with the fs module:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
const allFood = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), '/data/all-food-data.json'), 'utf-8')) as FoodItem[]
```

However this introduced a different error, where pages would no longer dynamically generate on request, and instead I would get a 404 error. If I put the fs.readFileSync() call inside the getStaticProps function, then I'd get a 500 error. These errors were on the vercel deployment only, and the local version still worked fine.

There may be a way to solve these problems, but I ended up with a different workaround:

**Workaround**

Simply splitting the JSON file into two smaller files and merging them together at run time solved the problem.

```
import allFood1 from '../data/all-food-data.json'
import allFood2 from '../data/all-food-data-2.json'
const allFood = [...(allFood1 as FoodItem[]), ...(allFood2 as FoodItem[])] as FoodItem[]
```

Not really a particularly satisfactory answer though, so I'll keep the question unanswered in the hopes to find a better way to overcome it.

Comment: Maybe the real solution here is to load the data through an API call instead of directly including the JSON file in your package? Including such a large JSON file into your build seems sub-optimal.

Comment: As I understand it the nextjs framework itself has getStaticPaths and getStaticProps functions specifically for generating optimised pages, and the server side portion where I'm using the JSON file should in theory not end up in the production build (except for specific data generated in the production build by the nextjs framework). I'm somewhat of a newb with nextjs though, so I'm just relying mainly on the docs for that info...

Comment: What are you using that JSON in your build process for? Do you actually need all its data in a single place?